# Can I call different SQL Scripts from within the VS Database project's post-deployment script

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, deployment, database-project

I have a massive insertion operation on a number of tables for a base-line database. I was trying to organize this task in multiple SQL scripts for individuals tables and dependent tables. I need to call the scripts in a sequence from the main post deployment SQL script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well I got a good chunk of help from here: http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/rrobinson/archive/2011/07/24/how-to-include-and-deploy-data-using-a-visual-studio-database-project.aspx

Comment: And http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/09/27/VSTS4DBP_3A00_-Post-deployment-scripts.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If there isn't already a post-deployment script in your project (possibly called Script.PostDeployment.sql) then add a new item of type SQL Server > User Scripts > Post-Deployment Script.
2. In this script, reference your insert scripts using a relative path like below. The scripts will be run in the order you list them. Example:

> ```
> :r .\InsertScripts\script1.sql
>
> :r .\InsertScripts\script2.sql
> ```

(Ignore any errors/warnings that say this is invalid syntax. Visual Studio treats these like placeholders and at build-time the contents of each script will essentially be inserted into the main SQL file.)

Comment: If you set "SQLCMD Mode", then you won't get errors. That's the toolbar button that looks like a document with an exclamation point next to it.